# set cookie and redirect for a multi language site using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if this can even be done using cookies but I feel I am close using my current code. I have a multi language site (english and french) and I'm trying to set a cookie when the user "logs in" which sets a cookie on success of log in. If the user has never logged in and try's to access another page in the site it redirects them to the english "log in" page as of now. Problem is if they try and access a french page it still redirects them to the english "log in". I'd like it to redirect them to the language they are trying to access if that makes any sense. All the french pages have the same name as the english pages but with an added "-fr.html" so "index-fr.html" is the french index and so forth.

this is close but it is creating a bad loop

jQuery:

```
 cookie set on ajax success: _siteNS.Utils.setCookie("x-access", true, 365);

 function checkCookie() {
    var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    var logInCookie = _siteNS.Utils.readCookie("x-access");

    //if the cookie is false and location is not the landing page set location to landing page
    if (!logInCookie && current_url != "/landing.html") {
      window.location.replace("/landing.html");
    }
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("-fr.html") > -1 && !logInCookie) {
      window.location.replace("/landing-fr.html");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Cookies are generally returned as strings, so be careful using Boolean checks on it (`!"false" === false`). Also, what does the "x-access" cookie represent? If it's just true if they are logged in, would should consider another cookie to represent language. Then it would be easy enough to add the "-fr" when needed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes the "x-access" cookie is just that, true if the user has successfully logged in. So should I just create another cookie say "x-access-fr" and use the same logic?

Comment: I would just create a "x-language" cookie that has "en" or "fr". Completely separate from whether the user is logged in. Then you change your logic: `if (!loginCookie && !current_url.includes("landing")) { window.location.replace("/landing" + (langCookie == "fr" ? "-fr" : "") + ".html"); }` and that's all you need.